# What size rubber grommet will a 3/4" PVC pipe fit (water tight) through?

Tags: sealing, pvc

What size rubber grommet do I need for a water-tight seal on a 3/4" PVC pipe?

For example, would this [rubber grommet](http://tinyurl.com/bp5qdqp) fit a 3/4" PVC Pipe?

[image]

Comment: water tight for potable water eg high pressure or just for some sort of drain

Comment: Yes, knowing the usage would help.

Comment: No high pressure. I'm converting a 37 gallon rubbermaid container into a holder for rain water. I'm drilling a hole in it and putting in a 3/4 PVC and I need a suitable grommet that won't leak. Thanks for any advice I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 6):

In these situations, I use bulkhead fittings. It saves the annoyance to getting this stuff to seal properly, any slight leverage and there's now a leak. These are available in several sizes at most plumbing supply stores. If there's a gentle curve to the surface this has to penetrate, I've used a large O-ring instead of the supplied gasket. They're available as glue type fittings, or internally threaded.

[image: PVC Bulkhead Fitting]

Comment: Any links to one of these by any chance? I can't seem to find them on-line

Comment: Searching for "bulkhead PVC fitting" finds dozens of places to buy.

Answer (score 2):

Schedule 40 3/4" PVC pipe has a nominal diameter of 1.050 inches. The grommet you have highlighted has a 1/2" bore or inside diameter. A grommet with a one inch bore should provide a tight seal. Just remember that water tightness also relys on a tight seal between the grommet and the container. This requires a hole as close to the shoulder diameter (not the overall diameter) as possible. As this type of container has a thin wall I would install the grommet with a generous amount of silicone sealer.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just built something similar. I tried all different types of gaskets, washers, etc. and all of them leaked under the pressure. I finally settled on a large metal washer on either side with a nut to apply pressure and **liberal** amounts of silicone.  It's been a week so far and no leaks. The other trick is to drill the holes slightly smaller than needed. I then heated up the plastic to make it pliable and pushed the pipe through. It's helped make a nice tight seal, along with the silicone.

Comment: You can also buy a threaded coupling that has a backing nut to accomplish the same idea as Steven but glue the PVC into the proper coupling

Comment: @UNECS The term is bulkhead fitting or tank bulkhead fitting. If the hole is drilled through a fairly flat area, this would be the best piece of plumbing to use.